# Collections of child objects are loaded, single child objects are overwritten (is this a lazy-loading issue?)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor, lazy-loading

I am using EF Core 5.08 (Blazor Server application).

I have a class `Assignment` with the properties:

```
public Guid AssignmentId { get; set;    
public Guid AssetId { get; set; }
public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }
public virtual List<Person> People { get; set }

public Assignment(){ 
     this.AssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid();
     this.Asset = new Asset();
     this.People = new List<Person>();
}
```

The class `Asset`:

```
public Guid AssetId { get; set; }    
public virtual List<Assignment> Assignments

public Asset() {
     this.AssetId = Guid.NewGuid();
     this.Assignments = new List<Assignment>();
}
```

`Assignment` has a many-to-many relationship with `Person`. `Asset` has a one-to-many relationship with `Assignment` (i.e. each Assignment references one `Asset` whereas each `Asset` references a collection of `Assignments`).

Entity Framework creates a join table `AssignmentPerson`; this, coupled with Lazy Loading enabled allows me to access and render properties of `Assignment.People` in razor components.

In razor components, when I access `Assignment.AssetId` the foreign key is as anticipated (i.e. it is the primary key of the corresponding `Asset` in the database).

Oddly, when I access and render `Assignment.Asset.AssetId` the `Asset` primary key is not the foreign key (`Assignment.AssetId`); it appears a new `Asset` is constructed instead in the place of the `Asset` I anticipate.

I assume it has something to do with lazy loading. How can the foreign key be correct but the `Assignment.Asset` be overwritten?

To get Assignments in the razor component I inject my service `AssignmentService` and call it's methods:

```
    public List<Assignment> Get(Guid workspaceId)
    {
        Workspace workspace = context.Workspaces.Find(workspaceId);
        return workspace.Assignments;
    }

    public Task<List<Assignment>> GetAsync(Guid workspaceId)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => this.Get(workspaceId));
    }
```

in

```
     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
          this.assignments = await assignmentService.GetAsync(Guid.Parse("//The Workspace.Guid"));
     }
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for reading over - added my approach to querying for context.

Comment: OK. Side note: replace Task.Run with async methods. But that is not the cause here.

Comment: Now we need to see the modeling of Assigment & Asset. OnModelCreating() or the attributes.

Comment: Also mention the EF version, this may have changed recently.

Comment: I still can't see any model-binding. Do you have an OnModelCreating?

Comment: Can you show the _complete_ Assignment class?  That `this.AssetId = Guid.NewGuid();` piece of code is suspect, I would throw it out.  Do you initiallze Assignment.Asset in a similar way?

Comment: Thanks @Henk Both Assignment and Asset have similar constructors each has a Guid Id which is initialised in their respective constructors. I don't have an OnModelCreating Method.

Comment: I was asking about `Assignment.Asset`. Does the constructor initialze that?

Comment: So the Asset and the Person instances in People are already initialised. Assignment is then initialised and the pre-existing Asset and People are referenced when setting Assignment properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any lazy loading. I'm not sure what Find() does but try this:

```
public List<Assignment> Get(Guid workspaceId)
{
    Workspace workspace = context
      .Workspaces
      .Include(ws => ws.Assignments).ThenInclude(a => a.Asset)
      .SingleOrDefault(ws => ws.WorkspaceId == workspaceId);
    return workspace.Assignments;
}
```

Furthermore, an Id should be generated by the Db, EF recognizes the `default(Guid)` as a NULL. So,

```
  //this.AssetId = Guid.NewGuid();  -- don't do this
```

and the Assignment constructor should **not** initialize the Asset property.

Initialzing a `List<>` property is OK.